# Find matching img src and removing if exists more than once - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

Im appending images into an unordered list as soon as the image in another list is clicked. So basically passing an image from one list to another. However I want to check if the image just passed to the new list exists already and if it does stop it from adding that image. (Or remove it, if its already appended).

Currently I have the below

```
$('.slick-slide').on('click', function(){
    var img = $(this).find("img");
    var img_src = $(img).attr('src');
    var full_src = "<li><img class='basket-image' src='"+img_src+"'/></li>";
    $(full_src).appendTo(".light-basket");
    checkBulbSrc(img_src);
});

function checkBulbSrc(clickedSource) {

    $('.light-basket').find('li').each(function() {
      var basket_img = $(this).find("img");
      var basket_img_src = $(basket_img).attr('src');

      if(basket_img_src == clickedSource){

      }
    });
};
```

I've got the append to work, however I now want my checkBulbSrc function to check if that image already exists, and not add it. Im thinking I might need to load the original image srcs into an array then check that before appending?

Any ideas?

D

Comment: keep track of them as you add them: `if (!previously_found[url]) { previously_found[url] = true; ... add to list ... }`

Comment: The "initialization" part of Marc's suggestion: `previously_found = {};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is the following.

```
//Get a reference to the element
var $lightBasket = $(".light-basket");

$('.slick-slide').on('click', function() {

    var img = $(this).find("img");
    var img_src = $(img).attr('src');
    var full_src = "<li><img class='basket-image' src='"+img_src+"'/></li>";

    //If the image doesn't exist, then append
    if ( !$lightBasket.find("img[src='"+img_src+"']").length ) {
        $lightBasket.append(full_src);
    }
});
```